# Owncloud "Add as trusted domain" button fails

Tags: owncloud

The 'Add as a trusted domain' button didn't do anything before now it takes me to an 'Error 404' page.

I can set the domain on the owncloud box by editing the file config.php and have done so but I still do not understand why the button doesn't work.

Comment: Just reopened https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/14320 as this issue is still not fixed as for today.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually override this button:
go to your installation folder in the config directory
open config.php  and add a line like this:

```
     'trusted_domains' =>
  array (
    0 => 'localhost',
    1 => 'yourdomain.com'
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just started working with ownCloud myself and happened upon a similar issue when I reboot my BananaPi. The BPi got assigned a new IP on my network and the only *Trusted* IP was the original IP. I wanted to see how I could allow more trusted domains or IPs. Quick search shows no wildcard options. Since I often add and remove devices from my network, I wanted to add a range, like 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.254.

Since config.php is simply included and can still run code, versus just being XML or something, we can build an array really quickly.

**config.php**

```
<?php

$local_ips = array();
$base = "192.168.0.";
for($i = 1; $i < 255; $i++){
  array_push($local_ips, $base . $i);
}

$CONFIG = array(
   // Other config items ...
  'trusted_domains' => $local_ips,
  // More config items...
);
```

This will create an array of IPs that can then be used as Trusted Domains. `$base` is the first 4 octets of your Private IP Subnet. If you use `192.168.0.0/24` or `10.0.1.0/24`, the `$base` would be `192.168.0.` or `10.0.1.` The `for()` loop will want to have a limit based on your network size.

Answer (score 0):

You must to include http or https before the domain. The general form is:

```
http://domain:port
```

or

```
https://domain:port
```

This is an example example:

```
http://10.0.0.1:8000
```

or

```
https://10.0.0.1:8000
```